# Next.js 13: loading.js not working when put in SSR folders

Tags: javascript, next.js, loading, react-suspense, next.js13

I've built a Next.JS app that has SSR user profiles and blog articles.

I'm having trouble getting the new Loading UI/loading.js from Next.js 13 to work.

**File Structure**

```
pages
├── profiles
│    └── [title].js
│    └── loading.js 
│       
│  
├── articles
│    └──[id].js
│    └──loading.js
│
│
├── index.js   
├── _app.js
```

**loading.js Code**

```
export default function Loading() {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}
```

I confirmed that my next.js version in `package.json`  is in fact `"next": "13.0.7",`

I've tried moving `loading.js` to the root pages directory, I've tried moving it into a component and then importing it into _app.js. None of this works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This works inside `app` folder, not `pages`.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea there was a difference between the two.